# PHP message: PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Tags: php, file-upload, nginx, upload

My script was running fine on apache server. But when i migrated to nginx server, i got the error:

> PHP message: PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

And there is the code:

```
        foreach($this->_uploaded as $name) {
        $file = pathinfo($name);
        $ad_count = $file['filename'];
        $path = '/images/ads/'.$friendly_name.'-black-friday-'.($ad_count).'-' . $this->createRandomString() . '.' . $file['extension'];

        if(!copy(__SITE_PATH . "/public/tmp/" . $name, __FRONTEND_PATH . $path)) {
            return false;
        }
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO stores_ads (stores_id, path, sort) VALUES (".$id.", '".$path."', ".(int)$ad_count.")");
        @unlink(__SITE_PATH . "/public/tmp/" . $name);
    }
```

Do you know the reason why?  I think it may get the wrong path of the upload folder? Or something wrong with nginx configuration?

This is the full code:

Comment: `$this->_uploaded` needs to be an array. Try `print_r($this->_uploaded)` and see if it's an array.

Comment: what is in `$this->_uploaded`???

Comment: Same thing, you need to make sure that `$this->_uploaded` is an array.

Comment: Your array might just be empty

Comment: @Duniyadnd: it wouldn't be a warning for an empty array

Comment: Do you have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: @Kevin Nguyen: have you read all the comments?

Comment: @zerkms yep. Im server admin. I'm not good at php btw.

Comment: echo __SITE_PATH . "/public/tmp/"; get that folder and check the write permission for nginx

Comment: @Kevin Nguyen: "Do you have an idea how to fix it?" --- you don't pass not arrays to `foreach` and the warning will not occur

Comment: @anhlc I gave it full permissions.

Comment: @zerkms I wondered why it worked on the old server with apache?

Comment: @Kevin Nguyen: it "worked" the same, but the warning there was hidden. But anyway, it does not matter if it worked somewhere any time before. The fact is: you are not passing an array hence there is a warning.

Comment: @zerkms i figured it out. It was nginx configuration. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add something like :

```
if (is_array($this->_uploaded)) {

//add your code
   foreach($this->_uploaded as $name) {
        $file = pathinfo($name);
        # code...
   }
}
```

hope this help :)

Comment: It didnt show the error anymore but i couldn't upload files.